# What is the best way to create control flow in templates?

Tags: templates

I am working on making my own "language/template" that "compiles" to another "language" called mcfunction. The main reasoning for this being that mcfunction does not contain loops or lambdas, so I essentially just want to add those two features to it. I am doing this by creating my own file extension and having a program I run convert my own custom syntax into syntax that makes sense to the mcfunction "language".

I've been mostly successful but adding the looping system I want has been difficult, and I wanted to know if there was a better way to do it than I currently am. My dad suggested I use a template, but I have no idea how that works and looking up how to do it I couldn't really find anything that helps.

Basically, the Syntax I want to implement is something like

```
[('foo','bar'),('baz','qux'),('quux','quz')](
    say {1}
    tellraw @a "{2}, {1}"
)
```

into

```
say foo
tellraw @a "bar, foo"
say baz
tellraw @a "qux, baz"
say quux
tellraw @a "quz, quux"
```

I need to replace every instance of this syntax in a giant string with the output there and ideally be able to escape single quotes, and put the input on multiple lines.
so

```
[
    ('foo','bar'),
    ('baz','qux'),
    ('quux','quz')
](
    say {1}
    tellraw @a "{2}, {1}"
)
```

should output the same thing.

I started working on a mess of a regex to handle this for me or break it down to help me, but my dad told me a templating engine might help and I couldn't figure out how to make that work so I came here for help. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: what does java have to do with anything, ie why is this tagged with java?

Comment: @depperm oh I forgot to mention. For constraints that would be kind of hard to explain, I have to make it in java.